# How to resize textarea according to content

Tags: javascript, textarea, height

I am adding the content to a textarea programmatically as shown below (where @muse.text is the content I want to display in the textarea)

```
$(@el).find('.context textarea').text @muse.text
$(@el).find('.context textarea').elastic()
```

However when I check the textarea, not the entire content is seen

[image]

Actual content I want to display

[image]

How can I programmatically set the textarea to the height of the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wriiten some code in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VdL4/). This will help you in simple way
**HTML**

```
<div id="contextwrapper">
    <div class="context">
        <textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut mauris dictum massa accumsan elementum at id sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubiliaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut mauris dictum massa accumsan elementum at id sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus id dui ac leo tincidunt sodales in sit amet leo. Etiam placerat vehicula lorem nec auctor. Aliquam luctus justo nec lacus laoreet tempus. Cras tristique sem ut lectus ornare non rutrum ipsum cursus. Vestibulum vel ipsum mi.

Mauris hendrerit, purus ut ultrices tristique, libero neque eleifend lectus, non ultrices odio nulla sed nisi. Quisque mollis posuere hendrerit. Cras lectus leo, dictum id viverra eu, interdum ac arcu. Cras eget mattis sem. In in eros magna. Nulla molestie, eros sed vulputate suscipit, nibh arcu pulvinar eros, nec placerat neque neque sed sem. Aenean nunc dui, sodales at aliquam elementum, porttitor sit amet felis. Nunc sed sapien eu quam venenatis convallis a nec ante. Donec varius nisl non neque posuere sed interdum diam tempus. Donec dui dolor, aliquet ac mattis eu, dapibus a enim. Nulla dui libero, molestie id suscipit laoreet, vehicula ut nunc. Donec eu libero urna, sit amet malesuada justo. Nulla bibendum vehicula dui, at tempor mi condimentum semper. Sed eget lorem dolor. Fusce suscipit erat quis nulla sollicitudin pellentesque.

Aliquam scelerisque mollis ante condimentum auctor. Proin laoreet pharetra egestas. Quisque lacinia ipsum in ligula tristique eget ornare leo scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed augue est, tincidunt ac lobortis placerat, imperdiet at neque. Suspendisse erat justo, elementum vel adipiscing non, mollis sit amet ligula. Sed vitae tempor nunc.

Vivamus molestie, nulla et posuere fermentum, ligula nibh suscipit orci, id interdum dui ipsum quis nisi. Vestibulum tincidunt urna quis elit semper ullamcorper. Maecenas scelerisque accumsan volutpat. Maecenas placerat accumsan vulputate. Proin rhoncus rhoncus tempor. Nulla hendrerit consectetur velit posuere commodo. Aliquam tempus malesuada sapien, nec hendrerit nibh dignissim id.

Curae; Phasellus id dui ac leo tincidunt sodales in sit amet leo. Etiam placerat vehicula lorem nec auctor. Aliquam luctus justo nec lacus laoreet tempus. Cras tristique sem ut lectus ornare non rutrum ipsum cursus. Vestibulum vel ipsum mi.

Mauris hendrerit, purus ut ultrices tristique, libero neque eleifend lectus, non ultrices odio nulla sed nisi. Quisque mollis posuere hendrerit. Cras lectus leo, dictum id viverra eu, interdum ac arcu. Cras eget mattis sem. In in eros magna. Nulla molestie, eros sed vulputate suscipit, nibh arcu pulvinar eros, nec placerat neque neque sed sem. Aenean nunc dui, sodales at aliquam elementum, porttitor sit amet felis. Nunc sed sapien eu quam venenatis convallis a nec ante. Donec varius nisl non neque posuere sed interdum diam tempus. Donec dui dolor, aliquet ac mattis eu, dapibus a enim. Nulla dui libero, molestie id suscipit laoreet, vehicula ut nunc. Donec eu libero urna, sit amet malesuada justo. Nulla bibendum vehicula dui, at tempor mi condimentum semper. Sed eget lorem dolor. Fusce suscipit erat quis nulla sollicitudin pellentesque.

Aliquam scelerisque mollis ante condimentum auctor. Proin laoreet pharetra egestas. Quisque lacinia ipsum in ligula tristique eget ornare leo scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed augue est, tincidunt ac lobortis placerat, imperdiet at neque. Suspendisse erat justo, elementum vel adipiscing non, mollis sit amet ligula. Sed vitae tempor nunc.

Vivamus molestie, nulla et posuere fermentum, ligula nibh suscipit orci, id interdum dui ipsum quis nisi. Vestibulum tincidunt urna quis elit semper ullamcorper. Maecenas scelerisque accumsan volutpat. Maecenas placerat accumsan vulputate. Proin rhoncus rhoncus tempor. Nulla hendrerit consectetur velit posuere commodo. Aliquam tempus malesuada sapien, nec hendrerit nibh dignissim id.
</textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="hidden"></div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#contextwrapper .context textarea{
    width:150px;
    height: 150px;
}

#hidden{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**    ​

```
var content = jQuery("#contextwrapper").find(".context textarea").val();
jQuery("#hidden").html(content);

divHeight = jQuery("#hidden").height();
divWidth = jQuery("#hidden").width();

jQuery("#contextwrapper").find(".context textarea").css({width:divWidth+'px', height:divHeight+'px'});
```

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, why is it necessary to copy the content to another div before finding the height?

Comment: the other `div#hidden` is just for temporary purpose so as to find the actual height, width of the content for the particular window . .

Comment: I tried this and encountered a small issue. The content that was set in the #hidden div seemed to have lost all the formatting i.e. paragraphs <p> etc. Hence if the original text has spaces between paragraphs, they are not considered when calculating the height of the div. How can I fix that?

Comment: i have added the contents with tags . . the tags aren't lost . . please check the link http://jsfiddle.net/4VdL4/1/

Comment: well this code will help you for sure . . i have first stripped the html tags of contents from #hidden div and then measured the height, width and then set the height, width of textarea accordingly . . please check the link http://jsfiddle.net/4VdL4/2/

Answer (score 1):

Have you done a [Google search](https://www.google.se/search?q=jquery+resize+textarea+content)?

First I found was this, http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: I am using another jquery plugin "elastic" which also helps to shrink textarea accordingly.

Comment: but I am still hitting the issue as above