# How I can keep the text like justify inside of the input when long string is typing down

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, input

I have a chat application using jquery, I want to when someone typing a long string justify it inside of the input as all chat do, can someone help me thanks in advance 
[image]

Comment: You mean like line-wrapping?

Comment: Please share your code showing what you've tried

Comment: yes line-wrapping

Comment: You need a textarea instead of multi line input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anyway to have a textarea "autofit" height based on the content at page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451611/is-there-anyway-to-have-a-textarea-autofit-height-based-on-the-content-at-page)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are using a `textarea` with specified width/columns for your message entry. Inputs are not suitable for what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a text area. If you want the rows to dynamically adjust, you can use the jQuery autosize plugin.

The demo below uses [Typed](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) to automagically type into the text area and [Lorem.js](https://github.com/f/loremjs) to generate the text. I added a watch function (`updateFn`) to check to see if the text area needed to be expanded because automated input does not act the same as physical user input. ;)

```js
var updateRate = 100;
var updateId = null;

(function($) {
  $.fn.numOfLines = function() {
    var lineHeight = parseInt(this.css('lineHeight'), 10);
    return Math.floor(this.attr('scrollHeight') / lineHeight);
  }
})(jQuery);


$(function() {
  $('.auto-size').autosize();
  var typed = new Typed('.auto-size', {
    strings: [ new Lorem().createText(2, Lorem.TYPE.PARAGRAPH) ],
    typeSpeed: 1000 / updateRate,
    preStringTyped: startUpdate,
    onComplete: cancelUpdate
  });
});

function updateFn(opts) {
  var lines = $('.auto-size').numOfLines();
  if (lines != opts.prevLines) {
    opts.prevLines = lines;
    $('.auto-size').trigger('autosize.resize');
  }
}

function startUpdate(arrayPos, self) {
  updateId = setInterval(updateFn, updateRate, { prevLines: 1 });
}

function cancelUpdate(self) {
  clearInterval(updateId);
}
```

```css
textarea[class="auto-size"] {
  resize: none;
  word-break: break-word;
  text-wrap: unrestricted;
}
.input-container label {
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-autosize@1.18.18/jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.9/typed.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/f/loremjs@ec971d2c7fc9a9b6a788095e0523a2794420f5c4/lorem.js"></script>
<div class="input-container">
  <label>Message: </label>
  <textarea cols="72" rows="1" class="auto-size"></textarea>
</div>
```