# How to make an expandable input form for chat

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've searched all over for a way to expand a text input form vertically like they do on modern chat app.

Everyone says that we should use textarea as the form input doesn't allow multi line but slack and spectrum are using forms... (discord use text-area though)

I would like to start with one line, and as user enter line break (shift + enter) the input expand to the top.

```css
.chat-footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 90vh max-content;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-i-bg);
  grid-area: i;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: var(--color-i-border-top);
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.chat-footer__form {
  align-self: end;
  display: grid;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: normal;
  background: none;
  line-height: 1;
}
.chat-footer__form::placeholder {
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.chat-footer__form-container-input {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
.chat-footer__form-container-btn {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}
.chat-footer__form-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.chat-footer__form * > button {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: 0;
  line-height: normal;
}
.chat-footer__form * > button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.chat-footer__form * > button:focus, .chat-footer__form * > button:active {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="chat-footer">
        <form class="chat-footer__form" role="form">
            <div class="chat-footer__form-container-input">
                <input type="text" class="chat-footer__form-input" placeholder="New message">
            </div>
            <div class="chat-footer__form-container-btn">
                <button class="chat-footer__form-btn" id="form-attach">Attach</button>
                <button class="chat-footer__form-btn" id="form-smiley">Smiley</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I'm not against using text-area if it's a better solution.

EDIT---

Finaly I used the solution with  contenteditable="true" with overflow:auto; on my main container, and used the this for the placeholder:

```
&[placeholder]:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
}
```

This did the trick. Thanks all for your answers !

Comment: A [<textarea>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) is a form input element just like `<input>`. Don't forget to read the [Styling with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Styling_with_CSS) section of the `<textarea>`. You should control the size of the `<textarea>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383032/8620333

Comment: If you got the solution please write it as an Answer below. The solution does not belong as part of your question (which hopefully is obvious if you think about it!). You are allowed and encouraged to answer your own questions

Comment: Finaly I used the solution with contenteditable="true" with overflow:auto; on my main container, and used the this for the placeholder:

&[placeholder]:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
}
This did the trick. Thanks all for your answers !

Answer (score 8):

You can have a div (no input and no textarea) and use [`contenteditable="true"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) attribute:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Now when users click on the div, they can write things! exactly like an input. So you just need to listen for the events of this div and for example when user presses `shift+enter` add a `<br>` tag or create some paragraphs.

I checked slack input and they use the same technique. there are also some other attributes which you may want to use:

```
 autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Message" dir="auto" contenteditable="true" role="textbox"
```

Comment: Oh yeah right this seems interesting solution ! I'll investigate this way, thanks a lot.

Comment: @NuoNuoLeRobot Good to hear that. I've once created a really simple WYSIWYG editor using this technique. Feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

To expand the input from bottom up:

```
.chat-footer__form-container-input {
  position: relative;
}
.chat-footer__form-input {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

To grow on shift+Enter, I would recommend textarea with JS input handler:

```
<textarea onkeypress="handleInput(event)" class="chat-footer__form-input" placeholder="New message"></textarea>
```

Set its height in absolute units of one line:

```
.chat-footer__form-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

And set the script with the shift+Enter behavior (only Enter submits the form):

```
function handleInput(e) {
  if(e.key=="Enter") {
    if(e.shiftKey) e.target.style.height = e.target.offsetHeight+20+"px";
    else e.target.form.submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, almost that ! but the form expands to the bottom, i would like it to expands to the top. Any idea how to make this happen ?

Comment: Did you try the css of with the relative-absolute position at the top of the answer?